# Extracting values from jwt token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, bearer-token, jjwt

I am trying to create a new user and authenticate the user using JWT token. The token is getting created but when I try to extract values from the token, all the values are being returned as `null`. `jwtUtil.extractClaims()` is supposed to extract the values from the token but all values are null.

```java
@GetMapping("/register/code/{token}")
public HashMap<String, Object> register(@PathVariable("token") String token, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
   HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
   System.out.println(token);
    if (!jwtUtil.isTokenExpired(token)){
        System.out.println("User");
        User user = new User(
                (String) jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token).get("email"),
                (String) jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token).get("phoneNumber"),
                (String) jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token).get("ppUrl"),
                (String) jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token).get("password")
        );
        System.out.println("User email "+jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token).get("email"));
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        // System.out.println(encodedPassword + " THIS IS THE ENCODED PASSWORD" +
        // authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        if (user.getProfilePicture() == null) {
            user.setProfilePicture("default.png");
        }
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        response.put("success", true);
        response.put("message", "User Registered is Succesfull");
        System.out.println("mail verified");
        try {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/app");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    } else {
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("message", "User Registered is not Succesfull!");
        return response;
    }
}
```

The `extractClaims()` is as follows:

```java
public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    System.out.println(Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody());
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}
```

How else can I extract the values from the token.

Edited to add the token generation code:

```java
public String generateToken(User user) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    claims.put("user", user);
    return createToken(claims);
}

private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims) {
    System.out.println("Claims inside createToken "+claims);
    return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
           .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
          .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that you add an object *(user)* to `Claims` and call the value of the object in `Claims` without calling the object *(user)*.

First you need to take the object in your hand and get the information from it.

Try creating a user like this:

```java
System.out.println("User");
LinkedHashMap userVariables = jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token)
                .get("user", LinkedHashMap.class);
User user = new User(
        (String) userVariables.get("email"),
        (String) userVariables.get("phoneNumber"),
        (String) userVariables.get("ppUrl"),
        (String) userVariables.get("password")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with extractClaim and not extractAllClaims. So like this:

```
public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
}
```

And create the method extractClaim:

```
public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}
```

Edit:
You should add the user while doing the Jwts builder with setSubject:

```
return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
       .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
      .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
```